# Navigate by RouteObject id in React Router v6

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm using React Router v6.
Is there a way to get or navigate to a route using the id of a RouteObject?

I know I can navigate by using a path like `router.navigate('frontend/collection/1234xyz')`.

But I'm looking for something like `router.navigateById('editColletion', {collectionId: '1234xyz')`.
Here is a snippet from my current code that initializes the Router:

```
import { Suspense }                         from 'react';
import { lazy }                             from 'react';
import { createBrowserRouter }              from 'react-router-dom';
import { RouteObject }                      from 'react-router-dom';

...

public static getRouter():Router {
    const Layout = lazy(() => import('app/views/Layout.r'));
    const HomePage = lazy(() => import('app/views/pages/HomePage.r'));
    const CollectionListPage = lazy(() => import('app/views/pages/CollectionListPage.r'));
    const CollectionPage = lazy(() => import('app/views/pages/CollectionPage.r'));

    const suspenseElement:JSX.Element = <>...</>
    const routes:RouteObject[] = [
        {
            path: '/frontend',
            element: <Suspense fallback={suspenseElement}><Layout /></Suspense>,
            children: [
                {
                    path: '',
                    element: <Suspense fallback={suspenseElement}><HomePage /></Suspense>,
                },
                {
                    id: 'home',
                    path: 'home',
                    element: <Suspense fallback={suspenseElement}><HomePage /></Suspense>,
                },
                {
                    id: 'listtColletion',
                    path: 'collections',
                    element: <Suspense fallback={suspenseElement}><CollectionListPage /></Suspense>,
                },
                {
                    id: 'editColletion',
                    path: 'collection/:collectionId?',
                    element: <Suspense fallback={suspenseElement}><CollectionPage /></Suspense>,
                },
            ],
        },
    ];

    const router:Router = createBrowserRouter(routes);
    return router;
}
```

I know the RouteObject can contain an id property but there is noting in the docs about what it's for or how it should be used.

Comment: I don't think so. The [`navigate` function](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/blob/main/packages/react-router/lib/hooks.tsx#L144-L150) takes a `To` object and an `options` object, or a `delta` value. Your request seems a bit odd, what exactly is the use case here?

Comment: @DrewReese One usecase would be that I have a path defined somewhere and later on I want to change it (say `collection/:collectionId?` to `collection/edit/:collectionId?`). Then I would need to go through my entire code to find all the instances where I use this route and change all of them. Whereas navigating to (or finding) a Route by id I would only need to change the route at the location where I actually define the routes.

Comment: Why not declare all your route paths in an object so you only need to edit them in the one place they are defined?

Comment: I Agree, but basically I just defined everything in the code already, so seems a bit weird to define every route again. If React Router doesn't have anything for this I will probably just write a small function that generates this definition object automatically.

Answer (score 1):

In a roundabout way it sounds like you are asking how to re-derive or re-implement the [`generatePath`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/utils/generate-path) utility function. And if the concern about needing to do a "find and replace" of route paths if/when you need to change them the solution for this is to declare your route paths in an object so there's only ever one place to edit them.

Example:

```js
const PATHS = {
  HOME: "/",
  EDIT_COLLECTION: "collection/:collectionId",
  ...etc
};
```

Use the paths and the `generatePath` function to create link targets.

```
import { Link, generatePath } from 'react-router-dom';

...

<Link to={generatePath(PATHS.EDIT_COLLECTION, { collectionId: '1234xyz' })}>
  Collection
</Link>
```

If you need to change the edit collection path then update the `PATHS` object.

```js
const PATHS = {
  HOME: "/",
  EDIT_COLLECTION: "collection/edit/:collectionId",
  ...etc
};
```

Comment: It's a start :) This way I will still end up with the paths defined twice. But I'll probably write some more code; for example to generate the PATHS object from the list of RouteObjects or maybe even a function that just gets you the correct path on the fly.
In any case thanks for the effort!